# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. When iterating over each string in string data

Tags: python, string, loops, text, iteration

good day,

My objective is to use `.lower()` for converting each string in the text data into the lower case. I tried to use `.count()` with a one-liner iteration. However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
# Iterating over the strings in the data. The data is called text
text_lowercase = ''.join((string.lower().strip() for string in text.count(0,)))
```

I want to use the one-liner iteration and do this. 
Help would be truly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: `text.count()` sounds like a number, so what is `for string in text.count(0,)` supposed to do? Clearly something like `for string in 10` makes no sense, but that is the sort of thing that you are doing.

Comment: What is text? A string? A list of strings? A dictionary?

Comment: I am trying to use count as a counter to iterate over each string instance in the '`text` data @JohnColeman

Comment: @RayToal `text` is string data

Comment: Then why not just `text.lower()` ??? ;-)

Comment: I want to build a function to only preprocess strings and then eventually want to be able to apply it where I pass in a list and it will target the strings in that list. Hence the iteration ! @RayToal

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like `data` is list of any object whatsoever, and you want an expression that will process the list by lowercasing the strings in that list, but keeping all of the non-strings in the list unchanged. Or do you want to drop the non-strings? That is, if you have `[3, "DOG", False]` do you want the result to be `["dog"]` or `[3, "dog", False]`?

Comment: well yes the data I want to pass in is a list. But my objective here is to take a string and process the strings only. Then I should be able to apply the function to the list to process the strings after. @RayToal

Comment: @JohnColeman I am trying to iterate over the text which is string data. I want to iterate over each string. I wasn't sure how to do it. That's why Im asking.

Answer (score 0):

`text.count` returns an integer. You try to iterate over it:

```
for string in text.count(0,)
```

but since it returns an integer, there is no `in` (it is not iterable). This is what the error message is telling you.

In the future, to better identify the source of an error, try to break up one-liners into multiple lines. This will give you better feedback on what part of your operation is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get is because the `count()` returns an `int` and then you try to iterate over that int. I think you should remove the `count` and you might be good to go (depending on how `text` looks like)

If you want to have a function that just lower cases the instances of `string` inside your `text`, maybe you can use something like this:

```
def lowercase_instance(text, string):
    return string.lower().join(text.split(string))
```

Now, if you have a list of texts then you can do something like this:

```
lowercase_texts = [lowercase_instance(text, string) for text in texts]
```

hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks! I tried something like this. The thing is I want to be able to take text and process it. So say, for example, if I pass in a list it will iterate over each string in the list and process the text. I do not want to do list comprehension.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. I want to create a function to pass in a string as a parameter. Only string data. I want this function to be able to iterate over each string instance in the string data and lower case the strings. Finally, the function should return a string  After that. I wish to use that function and pass in a list with strings. You do not need to write the function out I can do that but it is just the one-liner iteration I am having trouble with. get it now? @glhuilli

Comment: i took a shot at your comments in the code above, not sure if this is exactly what you want, let me know.

Comment: the function should only pass in a string as a parameter and nothing else. That string can be text or a message. You have two. can you alter it to only pass one paramter text or string? @ glhuilli

Comment: would that one parameter look like `'this'` (option1) or like `['this']` (option2)? In case it's option2, then what would be the list to iterate? In case it's option2, then what would be the instance you need to match, is it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues to point out here:

```
text_lowercase = ''.join((string.lower().strip() for string in text.count(0,)))
```

Naming the temporary variable `string` is a bad idea, as this looks a lot like the type name. Something like `s` is more common and readable.

Or perhaps `word` because that's what you are after it seems. This is the second problem, your approach seems to break down the string in characters, but from the comments it appears you'd like to operate on words? (your use of `strip` also suggests this)

You're joining on `''`, which results in all the parts of the string being joined with no space between them.

As others point out, `count` returns an integer, but you want to operate on the actual string. You indicated you only tried count to iterate and that's not needed in Python like it is in many other languages.

Putting it together for words:

```
text_lowercase = ' '.join([w.lower() for w in text.split(' ')])
```

Or if you're after characters:

```
text_lowercase = ''.join([ch.lower() for ch in text])
```

But then you could just:

```
text_lowercase = text.lower()
```

Perhaps you like words, but want to get rid of excess spaces?

```
text_lowercase = ' '.join([w.lower() for w in text.split(' ') if w != ''])
```

Or in shorthand:

```
text_lowercase = ' '.join([w.lower() for w in text.split(' ') if w])
```

Comment: thanks! @Grismar. Just one question. Assuming `text` is all strings which is the input  data. The output `text_lower` is a string or a list? I ask because I see list comprehension

Comment: You're correct in spotting a list comprehension - it's in there because `.join()` expects a list as input, so I generate the list of words and then join takes that list and turns it into a string again. `text_lower` will be a string.